# Needing specific bounds for an integration question so the answer isn't zero

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

There is a curve with parametric equations:

$x = a \cos^3 \theta$, $y = a \sin^3 \theta \space$ for $\space 0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$

Find the total length of this curve.

When I solve this I end up with:

length = $\frac{3}{2}a \left[-\frac{1}{2}\cos 2\theta\right]_0 ^{2\pi} = 0$

Which is obviously not correct, so I have to rearrange this into the form:

$6a \left[ -\frac{1}{2} \cos 2\theta \right] _0 ^{\frac{\pi}{2}} = 6a$

Which is correct.

My question is why before the rearrangement does the equation, for want of a better word, "lie" to me and make it seem like the length is zero? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\left(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right)^2 =9a^2(\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta)(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta).$$

If $a\gt0$, the square root of this is $3a\,|\cos\theta\sin\theta|$. So we need to be careful in the  parts of the world where $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ have opposite sign.